# SQL Server 2012: get the SQL code that fired a trigger, without DBCC INPUTBUFFER or sys.dm_exec_input_buffer

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, database-trigger

Is there a way of getting the SQL code that fired a trigger from inside the fired trigger, without using `DBCC INPUTBUFFER` or `sys.dm_exec_input_buffer`?

I need this for a trigger that logs the new value, the old value and the statement that made the change in that table.

Even though `DBCC INPUTBUFFER` resolves the challenge, I cannot use it because I need to use "INSERT INTO ... EXEC" in order to get the query that fired the trigger and the trigger is fired by many statements that already use "INSERT INTO ... EXEC", so I will get the error

> An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested

From my research, `sys.dm_exec_input_buffer` might do the trick, but I cannot use it since it is available only for SQL Server 2014 SP4 and newer (as mentioned here: [Get last command in SQL Server without DBCC INPUTBUFFER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19397828/get-last-command-in-sql-server-without-dbcc-inputbuffer)), and I am using an older version.

I have tried several ways of solving the problem but without success. I cannot get the SQL statement that fired the trigger but only the last executing statement which is the trigger.

To see the problem, take a look at the following code:

```
--Create the table that will have the trigger
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[___testTrigger]
(
    [text] [NVARCHAR!(50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.TestTriggerAuditLog 
ON  dbo.___testTrigger 
AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --Version 1: without "INSERT INTO ... EXEC" but does not get the text of the statement that fired the trigger. Instead, it gets the current running query, which is the trigger
    SELECT  sqltext.TEXT,
            req.session_id,
            req.status,
            req.command,
            req.cpu_time,
            req.total_elapsed_time
    FROM sys.dm_exec_requests req
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS sqltext
    WHERE req.session_id = @@SPID

    --Version 2: gets the statement that fired the trigger, but we need to use "INSERT INTO ... EXEC"
    DECLARE @inputbuffer TABLE (EventType NVARCHAR(30),Parameters INT,EventInfo NVARCHAR(4000))
    INSERT INTO @inputbuffer EXEC('dbcc inputbuffer('+@@Spid+') WITH NO_INFOMSGS')

    SELECT * FROM @inputbuffer AS I
END
```

I know that in a trigger is not ok to have `SELECT` statements! I did it just to make the example simpler.

Now, we can insert some data to see what we get:

```
--test
INSERT INTO dbo.___testTrigger (text) 
VALUES (N'This is a test test')
```

We will get the 2 selects returning different results, as can be seen in the bellow image.

[image]

Any ideas of what could I use to get the same result as `DBCC INPUTBUFFER` but without using "INSERT INTO ... EXEC" and without using `sys.dm_exec_input_buffer` as it is not available in my SQL Server version?

Answer (score 1):

```
create table dbo.abcd(id int);
go
create trigger dbo.triggerabc on dbo.abcd for insert, update, delete
as
begin

    declare @t table(query nvarchar(4000));

    insert into @t (query)
    select EventInfo
    from OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;', 
    '
    declare @spid nvarchar(10), @sql nvarchar(1000);
    select @spid = cast(session_id as nvarchar(10))
    from sys.dm_exec_requests
    where session_id > 50
    and wait_type = ''OLEDB''
    and wait_resource like ''SQLNCLI%(SPID='' + cast(@@spid as varchar(10)) + '')'';

    select @sql = ''dbcc inputbuffer('' +  @spid + '') WITH NO_INFOMSGS'';
    exec(@sql) with result sets( (EventType NVARCHAR(30),Parameters SMALLINT,EventInfo NVARCHAR(4000)) );
    '
    ) ;

    select * from @t;
end
go
insert into abcd(id) values(123)
go
insert into abcd(id) 
exec('select 456')
go

drop table abcd
go
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not bring the needed statement. 
It returns:
`exec('dbcc inputbuffer(@@Spid) WITH NO_INFOMSGS')    
WITH result sets( (EventType NVARCHAR(30),Parameters SMALLINT,EventInfo NVARCHAR(4000)) ) `

Comment: at least it works without errors. what was i thinking? OPENROWSET opens a new connection, different context, database...@@SPID is different. Adjusted the answer, still not tested.

Comment: edit: although it works, it is very edgy and a bit of an overkill, ayor.

Comment: yes, this works but you need extra permissions on the server and this is a limiting factor. I need to deploy this to servers where sysadmins do not agree to allow new permissions.
Additionally using OPENROWSET adds overhead, especially for a logging mechanism that will be triggered at any modification in the table.
This gets even more compounded if scaled to many tables that are logged.
So, even if it works, it cannot be used in a production environment :(

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple solution.

But first, since triggers don't fire on `select` it probably isn't very accurate to refer to "queries" firing the trigger. It would probably be more accurate to call them "statements."

Anyway, add a column to your table such as `StatementName varchar(10)` and then in each `insert` statement that will fire the trigger, add a value such as `'Statement1'`, `'Statement2'`, etc.

Then the trigger can just check the inserted row and know what statement fired the trigger.

Comment: The purpose of this is to create an audit log, logging the operations made on the data and what statements made the changes, needing to log changes that may be done by anyone in any way, including writing an Update statement to change the data. Hence the need for catching the script that did the change.
Unfortunately, your proposal is not a solution for this scenario.

Comment: Unfortunately then, it seems you are going to have to implement some kind of audit logging.